# ClassNotFoundException with Slick, sbt, and Postgres

Tags: postgresql, scala, sbt, slick

I'm getting a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver` when I try to follow the "Plain SQL" example at [typesafe](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.1/sql.html).

I have the following in my `build.sbt` `libraryDependencies`:

```
"postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901.jdbc4"
```

I use the following line in place of the example's h2 driver line:

```
Database.forURL("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/myDatabase:mySchema:myPassword", driver = "org.postgresql.Driver") withSession { ...
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

I agree, the driver is not in the classpath, so there may be something wrong with your SBT config.

However the dependency `"postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901.jdbc4"` looks fine, and that jar seems to contain the driver. So it seems this line is simply ignored.

Comment: You're probably right, there must be something wrong with sbt config, not sure what. I added an import line: import org.postgresql.Driver, and it worked. Even though the example clearly states that is not needed. I think the problem is that the driver is passed as a String into forURL call, and thus not compiled, causing no dependency to be resolved at compile time.

Comment: There's no need to "dependency resolved at compile time", it is perfectly legal to change version of a class between compile time and runtime. It is also perfectly ok to load a class from its fully qualified name at runtime

Comment: I agree, but this wasn't working for me, per my original post. Still not sure why, but compile-time workaround worked, so I'm moving on. Thanks!

Comment: According to the driver code I've seen, the Driver has a static initializing block that registers it to the DriverManager so maybe the class must be first loaded before being available in the DriverManager. I never had to do that but never used any Postgres driver so...

Answer (score 0):

this clearly shows the org.postgresql.Driver class ( available in jar) is not in CLASSPATH. Is it standalone , or available in any server ?

If standalone apps , `put jar in CLASSPATH` 
if available in app/web server , `put jar in webapp lib directory`

Comment: The driver is in CLASSPATH, but I was under impression that this shouldn't matter with sbt, and the dependency line should be handling that even if there's nothing in classpath. It certainly works for slick dependency, even though it's not in CLASSPATH